# ASP.NET 5: How to reload strongly typed configuration on change

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, configuration, configuration-files

I have been able to set up strongly typed configuration in ASP.NET 5, and it works perfectly. I have also set the configuration to reload automatically when the `.json` configuration files are changed. But this only seems to work if I use the untyped configuration. The strongly typed configuration class still retains the old values when the `.json` files are changed.

I'm setting up configuration like this:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    // Setup configuration sources
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json");
    Configuration = builder.Build()
        .ReloadOnChanged("config.json")
        .ReloadOnChanged($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json");
    /* ... (unrelated stuff edited away) ... */
}
```

And binding it like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    /* ... (unrelated stuff edited away) ... */
    services.AddOptions();
    services.AddInstance(Configuration);
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
    services.Configure<DbSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DbSettings"));
    /* ... (unrelated stuff edited away) ... */
}
```

(The configuration files looks like this:)

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "This": "that",
        "Foo": "bar"
        /* etc... */
    },
    "DbSettings": {
        /* (db settings here) */
    }
}
```

(And I correspondingly have a C# class like this:)

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string This { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    /* etc... */
}
```

When I acquire the `IOptions<AppSettings>` via dependency injection, it doesn't change when I change the `config.json` and `config.Dev.json` files. I have to restart the entire web app to make the config class update. But if I instead use the untyped `IConfiguration` instance, it automatically changes when I change the json files.

So the question is: How to make the strongly typed configuration change when I change the .json file, without having to restart the webapp?

Comment: Did you ever managed to overcome this limitation? Is it possible to force services.configure to load on file change?

Answer (score 2):

on asp.net core 1.1 it fixed with [IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#ioptionssnapshot)

Answer (score 0):

When `Configuration.GetSection()` is called, it will pass in that section once at startup.

In order to have the `AppSettings` option update at run-time, you must bind the `AppSettings` option to the configuration section.

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(option => Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(option));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since ASP.NET 5,  but currently the docs are clear with the `IOptions<T>` the changes are not read. With `IOptionsSnapshot` or `IOptionsMonitor`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0#the-options-pattern

The changes are also read when `Bind` is used, or the `Get<T>` method, but not just calling the `GetSection`

Comment: What if we are in a `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` project that doesn't have a web application builder?